# Disproving asymptotic relation

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to disprove that $\forall f: N\rightarrow R^+,\forall g: N\rightarrow R^+, f \in \Omega(g) \iff \lfloor f\rfloor \in \Omega(\lfloor g\rfloor).$

However I need some hints.

Comment: What do you have so far ?

Comment: @Bartek First I was trying to prove it using chains of inequalities:
For the implication in the forward direction I came up with:
[f]+1 >= f >= g >= [g]
For the implication in the reverse direction I came up with:
f >= [f] >= [g] >= g-1
However, I came out with nothing.
Then I tried to disprove it, but it seems I need a counterexample (two functions) to disprove either the implication in the reverse direction or in the forward direction. But I couldn't think of the two functions.

Comment: Hint: There are constant functions $f,g$ which form a counterexample.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus Thank you! I have the two functions now: f(n) = 0.25, g(n) = 1

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Really, I think the statement is true for $f=\Omega(g)$ and $g$ and $f$ constant functions.

Comment: @oksana So you solved it?

Comment: Yes I did. If f(n) = 0.25 and g(n) = 1, then f >= 0.25*g(n) for all n, which shows f is in Omega(g). However, floor(f(n)) = 0, and floor(g(n)) = 1, thus floor(f) is not in Omega(floor(g)).

Comment: Please update your question with your early attempts, and post an answer with your final solution.

Comment: @A.Schulz That depends on the definition of $\Omega$ and the set of functions it admits.

Answer (score 2):

I disproved it by a counterexample (two functions) to disprove the implication in the forward direction. If $f(n) = 0.25$ and $g(n) = 1$, then $f \geq 0.25 g(n)$ for all $n$, which shows $f \in \Omega(g)$. However, $\lfloor f(n) \rfloor = 0$, and $\lfloor g(n) \rfloor = 1$, thus $\lfloor f(n) \rfloor$ is not in $\Omega(\lfloor g(n) \rfloor)$.

Comment: Whether or not the last statement is true depends on the precise definition of $\Omega$ at hand. $0$ is a wicked corner-case for some variants but not for others.